# Deserialize complex object with Json

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net, json-deserialization

How would I deserialize this with JSON.NET. I keep getting a "cannot perform binding on a null reference" exception. Here is the code, and the JSON output below:

```
            var json = client.DownloadString("https://myapp.tpondemand.com/api/v1/UserStories?take=999&include=[Tasks[Id,Name,TimeSpent]]&format=json");

        dynamic output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        string nemo = output.items[1].Id[0];

        Console.ReadLine();


{
```

"Items": [
    {
      "Id": 395,
      "Tasks": {
        "Items": []
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": 394,
      "Tasks": {
        "Items": []
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": 393,
      "Tasks": {
        "Items": []
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": 336,
      "Tasks": {
        "Items": []
      }
    },
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

If you know Json format just create datacontracts and deserialize them.

For example

```
    [DataContract]
    public class ItemJson
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<TaskJson> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TaskJson
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<ItemJson> Items{ get; set; }
    }
```